# Redirect response with pure node.js without frameworks or npm modules

Tags: node.js

I am writing a simple application on pure node.js without the use of frameworks and npm modules. There was a problem - when the application is redirected, it hangs and after a few minutes an error appears in the browser window: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.
At the same time, if, during the hangup, I quickly press ctrl + c and then quickly restart the server, the request will be fulfilled, and I will successfully redirect to the necessary page.
On php, a similar procedure works successfully.

I tried many different ways, ranging from replacing the status from 302 to 301, writing the status and title directly:

```
response.statusCode = 302;
response.setHeader('Location', url);
response.end();
```

ending with adding a host, protocol and port directly:

```
url = 'http:localhost:3000/${url}';
response.writeHead (302, {'Location': url});
response.end();
```

```
    // Redirect.js Redirect class
    /**
    * Which page will the user be redirected to
    * @param path
    * @param data
    * @return {*}
    */
    to(path, data = {}){
        const session = require('../session').getInstance();

        if(Object.keys(data).length) {
            session.set('redirect', data);
        }

        let url = '/${path.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '')}/';

        this.response.writeHead(302, {'Location': url});

        this.response.end();
    }
```

```
    // php similar code for example
    // helpers.php
    /**
     * @return string
     * http(s)://example.com
     * returns the domain name of the application, including the protocol
     */
     function domain()
     {
        $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
        $domainName = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

        return $protocol . $domainName;
     }
     // Redirect.php Redirect class
     /**
     * @param $path
     * @param array $data
     *
     * Which page will the user be redirected to
     */

    public function to($path, $data = [])
    {
       if($data) {
          Session::put('redirect', $data);
       }

       $url = domain() . '/' . trim( parse_url($path, PHP_URL_PATH), '/' );
       header("Location: ${url}");
       exit();
    }
```

I expect the user to be redirected to the desired route, but as a result, the application freezes, and a few minutes later an error occurs in the browser window: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.
But if you quickly restart the server, the request will be executed, and the redirection will be successful.

Comment: Your Node.js code on "redirect response" is correct, please check my "answer".

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is not an answer, but to show OP that his Node.js code strategy is correct (I'm not able to post multiple lines of code in the comment), and the root cause of the problem lie on function `to()` or the code invoke that function.

The Node.js code strategy shown in the question is correct. Here is a simple demo which redirects response with pure Node.js without frameworks or npm modules:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/path1') {
    res.statusCode = 302;
    res.setHeader('Location', '/path2')
    res.end();
  } else {
    res.write('Hello Sun!');
    res.end();
  }
}).listen(3000);
```

HTTP request `GET /path1` would be redirected to `/path2`, and display result as `Hello Sun!` in browser.

Comment: And what about POST methods? what if I try to redirect the user to the GET route during the POST method? For example, when authorizing a user, I want to redirect him to the profile page `/profile/{id}`, which is registered as a GET route. Can i do this?

Comment: It works for `POST` too. I tried `POST /path1` in postman and get `Hello Sun!` response.